# Issue in ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

I am Detecting the SD card content for my app using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE method in Android version 11. But the Android developer website adds one issue about this method, which is:

Access restrictions:
On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access to the following directories:

- The root directory of the internal storage volume.
- The root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card is emulated or removable.

  - A reliable volume is one that an app can successfully access most of the time.

So I am confused about whether I use ACTION OPEN DOCUMENT TREE  Method or not. Please give me some proper solution.

Comment: I think it's saying that if `/` is the root directory, you cannot use ACTION OPEN DOCUMENT TREE on that directory, but you may be able to do so on `/subdir` — a subdirectory of the root directory — if the permissions on the directory allow it (and it isn't the root directory of a reliable SD card volume which is mounted somewhere on `/`).  It probably means you can't (easily) search the entire directory tree with your app; you have to know where you are looking for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only can't access to the **root** directory
you can apply access to all sub directories.
I suggest you to see this GitHub sample project that gets access to WhatsApp status directory although it's created by another app:
https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver/blob/master/app/src/main/java/a/gautham/statusdownloader/SplashActivity.java

you can create your own directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent and get access to it.

```
    fun openDirectory(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker when it loads.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
}
```

All of these concepts is about user privacy
these articles have written by Google can give you idea :
[android 11 storage changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific